# Title bar picture shows up on one page, but not the others

Tags: javascript, html, css, jpeg

I am doing a website for someone and I have their logo in the title of my html. The home page has the logo on it, but when I open any of the other pages for the site, the picture doesn't show up. Anyone know what the problem might be?

```
<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title src = "./images/Title.jpg" alt = "header">Sample Title</title>
</head>
```

This is how it looks on all the other pages as well.

Comment: The tag title must add it on each page.

Comment: You should to use [favicon](https://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon) to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You must define the

```
<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title src = "./images/Title.jpg" alt = "header">Sample Title</title>
</head>
```

in your each HTML page

Answer (score 0):

You didn't see it simply because you didn't extend the icon to other pages. Just copy the same title and paste to all of your pages